# Display user data with post data in one flatlist. Merge two Firebase firestore collections into one end result

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I have a post feed combining of two firebase firestore collections.

userPosts = [] // collectionGroup() query of all users images

users = {} // the users data after for looping posts results

I'm currently getting both the posts from the post collection and the users data from the users collection after for looping the post uids.

This is working fine and shows the user object combined with the post object in the console.log() but It will not show in the flatlist when combining this end result to a state hook!

Basically, it seams to be working fine but I can't display it. I need the end result to be the post with the users data retrieved after for looping.

Again, console.log shows correct merge of data, attaching to state hook and displaying in flatlist is not working.

My code:

```
    useEffect(() => { // showGlobal feed
        if (showGlobalFeed) {
            firebase.firestore()
                .collectionGroup("userPosts")
                .orderBy("creation", "asc")
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {

                    let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const data = doc.data();
                        const id = doc.id;
                        const uid = data.uid;
                        return { id, uid, ...data }
                    })

                    for(let i = 0; i< posts.length; i++){
                        firebase.firestore()
                        .collection("users")
                        .doc(posts[i].uid)
                        .get()
                        .then((snapshot) => {
                            if (snapshot.exists) {
                                let user = snapshot.data();
                                user.uid = snapshot.id;


// the below cosloe.log works fine.

                                console.log('\nFOR LOOP COMBINED ==========> \n',[posts[i], user])

// the hook fails to display combined data correctly
                                setGlobalPosts([posts[i], user])
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log('does not exist')
                            }
                        })
                    }
                   // console.log({...posts})
                })
            }

    }, [showGlobalFeed])


Flatlist = data={globalPosts}
```

Comment: Try by spreading data like this setGlobalPosts([...posts[i], ...user])

Comment: Hi Thanhal - it gives the error "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.] non-array objects must have a [Symboly.iterator]()method " ??

Comment: To add, if I take away the 3 dots I get only two posts in the flatlist, one for "posts" Array and one for "users" object, they're not combined into one data set.

Comment: Can you share a sample post data, users data and expected combined data

Comment: Sure I'll do that after bank holiday. However, the data sets are quite large. It may be best to tell me what to look out for. For example, i'm getting firebase timestamp errors on the frontend so not sure if that creates this issue. The error is non-serializable values were found in the navigation state.

Comment: just to verify post data & user data are objects and similar.  Also try setting global post outside for loop. like initialize an empty array before for loop and push data to that array inside for loop, then after for loop set that array to global post

Comment: ok great. Let me try that and see if we have any luck! The data should be fine as I'm getting both user data and user posts separately in the app. Also, it displays the two data sets as objects with their values in the console.log([posts[i], user]).